# dragging not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I m trying to resize as well drag a div in my code.code is below,but i m not able to drag the div at all in ie but i can do the same in chrome.But resizing works in both.Please check and guide me on how can i make dragging work as well in ie.

```
interact('.divname')
  .resizable(true)
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target;

    // add the change in coords to the previous width of the target element
    var
      newWidth  = parseFloat(target.style.width ) + event.dx,
      newHeight = parseFloat(target.style.height) + event.dy;

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width  = newWidth + 'px';
    target.style.height = newHeight + 'px';

    //target.textContent = newWidth + '×' + newHeight;
  });  


interact('.divname')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: function (event) {
      var target = event.target,
          // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
          x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
          y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

      // translate the element
      target.style.webkitTransform =
      target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

      // update the posiion attributes
      target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
      target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    },
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });


<div class="divname">
</div>
```

Comment: You should modify your question and include that you're using interact.js. What version of IE are you testing?

Comment: i m testing it in ie9 and ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support `transform`, so your `onmove` handler will not work there. In addition, `textContent` is not supported in IE8, so your `onend` handler would not work as well.

For IE9, you can do a transform but you'll need to use a vendor prefix of `ms`, similar to `webkit`.

Comment: i removed the points in onend,and in onmove,i modified transform to mstransform but still it doesnot work in ie9.

Comment: Did you do "msTransform" (with a capital T?)